# SwiftUI Form Picker with text and Image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a form picker that shows the currently selected image resource at the top level and when the user selects it to show the detail, I want it to show all of the image resources available.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
                Picker("Background image:", selection: $task.background) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< backgroundImages.count) {
                        Image("Background\($0)").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                        Text("Background\($0)")
                    }
                }
```

The problem with this is that in the detail screen I get:

[image]

The image is blank and the image and text appear on 2 different rows.

I have tried wrapping the Image and Text lines in an HStack, but that gives a compile time error on some other line. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should compile & work well (tested with replaced system images, Xcode 11.2)

[image: demo]

```
Picker("Background image:", selection: $task.background) {
    ForEach(0 ..< backgroundImages.count) { i in
        HStack {
            Image("Background\(i)").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 35, alignment: .center)
            Text("Background\(i)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that response. That fixes the first half of my problem in that it displays the Text and image on the same row. Unfortunately the image, while displayed correctly in the Master view, is still a white rectangle in the detail view. Remember that this is a Picker in a form so that it does not display as a wheel picker, but as a Master/Detail picker.